# Counter for Calculated Column

Tags: calculated-column, view, counter

I have a calculated column with specific formula, which returns single number. The number represnts number of days between task created and task closed. I want to display an average counter to this task. When I go to "modify this view" then "totals" my column is not displayed there . How do I add average counter to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a calculated column for totals within a view.  You could use a workflow to move the information over to a numeric field and then choose average within your views for that column.

Your formula could be:

```
=DATEDIF(Date1,[Date 2],"d")
```

This would calculate the number of days between the two dates.